# What is the correct jmp_buf size?

Tags: gcc, arm

I got a library compiled wit GCC for the ARM Cortex-M3 processor compiled as static lib. This library has a jmp_buf at its interface.

```
struct png_struct_def {
#ifdef PNG_SETJMP_SUPPORTED
    jmp_buf jmpbuf;
#endif
    png_error_ptr error_fn;
    // a lot more members ...
};
typedef png_struct_def png_struct;
```

When I pass a `png_struct` address to the library function it stores the value not to `error_fn` but the last field of `jmpbuf`. Obviously it has been compiled with another assumptions of the size of a `jmp_buf`.

Both compiler versions are arm-none-eabi-gcc. Why is the code incompatible. And what is the "correct" jmp_buf size? I can see in the disassembly that only the first half of the jmp_buf is used. Why does the size changes between the versions of GCC when it is too large anyway?

**Edit:**
The library is compiled with another library that I can't recompile because the source code is not available. This other library uses this interface. So I can't change the structure of the interface.

Comment: jmp_buf type is unspecified (7.13.2) and you can not rely on its size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may simply re-order the data declaration.  I would suggest the following,

```
typedef struct if {
    int some_value;
      union
        {
          jmp_buf jmpbuf;
          char pad[511];
        } __attribute__ ((__transparent_union__));
} *ifp;
```

The issue is that depending on the **ARM** library, different registers maybe saved.  At a maximum, 16 *32bit* general purpose registers and 32 *64bit* NEON registers might be saved.  This gives around 320 bytes.  If you `struct` is not used many times, then you can over-allocate.  This should work no matter which definition of `jmp_buf` you get.

If you can not **recompile** the library, you may try to use,

```
typedef struct if {
    char pad[LIB_JMPBUF_SZ];
    int some_value;
} *ifp;
```

where you calculated the `jmp_buf` size.  The `libc` may have changed the definition of `jmp_buf` between versions.  Also, even though the compiler names match, one may support floating point and another one does not, etc.  Even if the versions match, it is conceivable that the compiler configuration can give different `jmp_buf` sizes.

Both suggestion are **non-portable**.  The 2<sup>nd</sup> suggestion will not work if your code calls `setjmp()` or `longjmp()`.  Ie, I assume that the library is using these functions and the caller allocates the space.

Comment: My description shows (not so explicit) that my compiler creates a larger `jump_buf` so there is no space for padding.

Comment: Right, that is why I proposed the 2nd solution.  `LIB_JUMPBUF_SZ` is a define that the original library is using; you can't use your compilers version.